# cannot start ECL when using QuickLisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, quicklisp, ecl

```
$ecl
;;; Loading "/home/***/quicklisp/setup.lisp"
;;; Loading #P"/usr/local/lib/ecl-12.7.1/cmp.fas"
;;; Loading #P"/usr/local/lib/ecl-12.7.1/asdf.fas"
ASDF could not load sockets because
An error occurred during initialization:
Error while trying to load definition for system sockets from pathname
/usr/local/lib/ecl-12.7.1/sockets.asd:
No applicable method for SOURCE-FILE-TYPE with arguments of types COMPILED-FILE PREBUILT-SYSTEM.

$cat ~/.eclrc 
;;; The following lines added by ql:add-to-init-file:
#-quicklisp
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp"
                                   (user-homedir-pathname))))
(when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
    (load quicklisp-init)))
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide any information about the version of quicklisp or the version of ECL you are using, what makes it hard to answer your question.

I presume you are using ECL 12.7.1, which is too old to work with recent versions of ASDF+quicklisp. Moreover, there was a problem with a recent quicklisp that shipped a version of ASDF that was incomplete: it did not load ASDF-bundle and support loading precompiled libraries.

All these problems have been solved in the CVS/git sources and I will produce a new release any time soon.

Juanjo

Comment: I don't understand the remark about asdf-bundle. Is it a separate file or part of asdf.lisp?

Comment: QL is version 2012112500 which should be newest. ECL is indeed 12.7.1